# Free to use (CCL) animations to sound design

Tags: sound-design, animation, effects, creative-commons, recommendations

I'm trying to build my showreel as a sound designer, but I mainly only have short films to show. I was wondering if anyone knew where I could find good quality animations licensed under Creative Commons (free to use with my own sound design).

John

Answer (score 2):

For my showreel I also used mainly short films that I worked on, but I edited it down to just the sections that I thought were the best bits.  I think it can work well as a montage.

Answer (score 1):

You might get lucky on the [Internet Archive](http://www.archive.org/search.php?query=collection%3Aanimationandcartoons) site. The link will bring you to the animation section.

Comment: Thanks Andrew, but all the material I've seen at the Internet Archive doesn't seem very good quality for a showreel. 